# How to rename filename before submitting form

Tags: php, jquery, forms, internal-server-error

How to rename filename before submitting the form to php page, because if  i upload images with single quote filenames, the server is throwing 500 internal error

so i want to rename filename using jquery in the frond end itself

Example:

```
goo'gle.jpg to google.jpg
```

please help me to solve this problem or any suggestion ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Show us ur code!!!

Comment: i am getting this error  while uploading single quotes                              ModSecurity: Access denied with code 44 (phase 2). Match of "eq 0" against "MULTIPART_STRICT_ERROR" required.

Comment: You can't do it.  Your problem is with the server code, so fix that.  The linked (duplicate) question explains why.

Comment: Simply  rename the file that you upload.
or (disable this security rule in /etc/{path}/mod_security.conf by commenting the line " SecRule MULTIPART_STRICT_ERROR "!@eq 0" \" or by .htaccess file - NOT RECOMMENDED AT ALL)

This error is caused by mod_security blocking a potentially malicious upload. While it may be completely harmless, mod_security has no way of knowing if it is harmless or not and the content may contain special character such as a single or double quote within the file name which is often used by attackers to inject malicious scripts into websites.

Answer (score 1):

Check this line:

```
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
```

here **$name** is the name of your file name, you can put your logic to create a new name and upload the file with that name.

Comment: i want to do with jquery only at frond end not with php

Comment: And why you want it so?

Comment: i am getting this error  while uploading files with single quotes   in production instance     :                      ModSecurity: Access denied with code 44 (phase 2). Match of "eq 0" against "MULTIPART_STRICT_ERROR" required.